# How to set the x value for High Charts error bar

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to specify both `x` and `y (min, max)` co-ordinates for an error bar (confidence interval) in HighCharts?  I'm able to use this format for normal series, but not when `type: 'errorBar'` is set.

i.e., instead of this:

```
data: [
    [0.06, 0.175], 
    [], [], [], 
    [0.49, 0.65], 
    [], [], [], [], [], 
    [0.395, 0.57], 
    [], [], [], [], [], [], [], 
    [0.17, 0.34], 
    [], [], [], [], [],
    [0.07, 0.17]
]
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
data: [
     {x:0, y:[0.05, 0.2]}, 
     {x:4, y:[0.48, 0.68]}, 
     {x:10, y:[0.38, 0.58]}, 
     {x:18, y:[0.16, 0.36]}, 
     {x:24, y:[0.03, 0.23]}
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, just not like that :)
The parameters for the data point object are x, low, high.

You can specify that two ways, either as an object:

```
{x:0, low:0.05, high:0.2}
```

or as a simple array:

```
[0, 0.05, 0.2]
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/290/